# How to know when certain terms are negligible in an infinite series.

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

I was doing a this limit problem: $$\lim_{n \to \infty } \frac{1}{1+n^2} +  \frac{2}{2+n^2} +  \cdots + \frac{n}{n+n^2}$$

The apparent solution to this problem is that the incrementing terms in the denominator are negligible so we don't have to consider them, but the terms in the numerator are not negligible, so the the entire infinite sum simplifies to: $$\lim_{n \to \infty } \frac{1}{n^2} +  \frac{2}{n^2} +  \cdots + \frac{n}{n^2}=\lim_{n \to \infty } \frac{n^2+n}{2n^2} = \frac{1}{2} $$

Why are the terms in the denominator negligible, but those in the numerator are not? And if possible, is there a good method to figure out which terms you can safely ignore in problems like these?

Comment: How did you simplify the sum given in the question? The sum that is in the question and the one that you've solved are clearly different. Please make the appropriate edits or correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @RiverX15 The solution I was told for this problem was that the incrementing terms in the denominator are negligible compared to $n^2$ as n tends to infinity, so we can safely ignore these terms and write $\frac{1}{1+n^2} as \frac{1}{n^2}$ and so on for every term.

Comment: That is not a valid argument. A way that you can characterize "negligible" is as something that you can remove and give you the same result. A proper argument can be that the given sum is less than or equal to $\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{k}{n^2}=\frac{n^2+n}{2n^2}$ and greater than or equal to $\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{k}{n+n^2}$.

Comment: @plop Thanks for clarifying this! However, I still want to know why the terms in the denominator are negligible compared to those in the numerator, as well if there is any method to easily identify if a term is negligible or not.

Comment: @ShudheshVelusamy Sorry I did not notice that. Thanks for the clarification.
An off topic question: Are you a JEE aspirant?

Comment: What I am saying is that the notion of negligible here is useless. When you remove them you get an upper bound. The only reason why they are negligible is because you can prove that that upper bound has the same limit. But if you had to prove in some other way that the limit was the same, then whatever "negligible" was was not used in any deduction.

Comment: @plop So you're saying that for these types of questions I should just trying finding lower and upper bounds (i.e apply squeeze theorem) rather than use the hand-wavy notion of certain terms being negligible?

Comment: @ShudheshVelusamy You can use the technique used below : the lower bound for a sum of terms, is the number of terms times the smallest term. Similarly , an upper bound is the number of terms times the biggest term. This should have been given in better detail in the answer below, but either way that is the main takeaway from this problem.

Answer (score 3):

Do it by sqeezing, let $S_n=\sum_{k=1}^{n} t_k$
$$t_k=\frac{k}{k+n^2} \implies \frac{k}{n+n^2}<t_k<\frac{k}{n^2}$$
Then $$\frac{\sum_{k=1}^{n}k}{n+n^2} < S_n <\frac{\sum_{k=1}^{n}k}{n^2}$$
$$\implies \frac{n(n+1}{2(n+n^2)}<S_n<\frac{n(n+1)}{2n^2}\implies \lim_{n \to \infty} S_n=\frac{1}{2}.$$

Comment: Thanks for the rigorous solution to the problem!